# Задать гет параметр в конфигурационном файле

Tags: nginx

```
set $root_path /var/www/user/data/www/open;
```

Указываем каталог в котором расположен файл. Вопрос в том, возможно ли объявить `get` параметр в конфигурационном файле сайта(`nginx`). Так чтобы в `index.php` его достать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, нельзя. ведь  Nginx не предназначен для обработки или манипуляции GET-параметрами в запросах клиентов. Для решения проблемы вам лучше взять скрипты на серверной стороне, например, написать обработчик на PHP и использовать Nginx для проксирования запросов к этому скрипту.